# Calling web service "400 Bad Request" error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to call a webservice in my C# ASP.Net MVC3 application.
This is the source code:

```
public string getCourseSchedule()
{
    string url = "http://192.168.1.198:15014/ShoppingCart2/CourseSchedule";
    string data = "Months&StatesMX&Zip=&Miles=&ProgramCodes=&EventCode=&PaginationStart=1&PaginationLimit=3";
    byte[] bytes          = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var myReq             = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myReq.Method          = "POST";
    myReq.ContentLength   = data.Length;
    myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    string responseString = "";

    using (Stream requestStream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse())
    {
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

The code is returning a "400 Bad Request" error. This is how I'm doing it in javascript and it works.

```
Mexico_Schedule: {"Months": null,
                  "States": [{"State: "MX"}],
                  "Zip": "",
                  "Miles": "",
                  "ProgramCodes": null,
                  "EventCode": null
                  "PaginationStart": 1,
                  "PaginationLimit": 3
};

$.ajax({
    async:       true,
    cache:       false,
    type:        'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    url:         "http://192.168.1.198:15014/ShoppingCart2/CourseSchedule",
    data:        JSON.stringify(Mexico_Schedule),
    dataType:    'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Fired when the request is successful');
        // Do something with results
    }
});
```

What modifications do I need to make to get the C# version working?

Comment: That's unlikely to work in javascript. You have specified `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;` and you are sending a JSON request payload. Or maybe the webservice you are trying to call doesn't respect or care about any HTTP protocol standards?

Comment: Sorry, but it does work.

Comment: Oh then the webservice you are calling's pretty damn crap. I mean you are setting content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you are sending `application/json` payload and it works? WTF man, you may submit a bug to the authors of this crap. I can't even believe people are still writing such crap and releasing it to the public.

Comment: If you can't be civil, don't freaking reply.

Comment: No, I just express my opinion, that's all.

Comment: If I set it to application/json, it returns a 400 Bad request.

Comment: WOW, that's even worse :-) Specifying the correct content type in this case doesn't work. Are you sure you wanna continue calling this (how you call it?) *service*? I am talking about the javascript version here.

Comment: Please take your OPINIONS elsewhere, they are not needed here.

Comment: Is it in the javascript version that you specified `contentType: 'application/json'` that didn't work? Maybe I misunderstood you. If you specified this content type in your C# version then make sure that you JSON encoded your request payload using a JSON serializer. But then again if you are saying that setting `contentType: 'application/json'` in your javascript version didn't work then my comment about the crapiness of this service stands completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just form your `data` (using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)) as:

```
var obj = new
{
    States = new[] { new{ State = "MX" } },
    Zip = "",
    Miles = "",
    PaginationStart = 1,
    PaginationLimit = 3
};

string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: Errors: "Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead."  and "The name 'State' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: @MB34 I updated the answer by adding a small `new`. Try again, I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather try to simplify your code using a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and a [`JSON serializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
public string getCourseSchedule()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "apoplication/json";
        var url = "http://192.168.1.198:15014/ShoppingCart2/CourseSchedule";
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            States = new[] { new { State = "MX" } },
            Zip = "",
            Miles = "",
            PaginationStart = 1,
            PaginationLimit = 3
        });
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] result = client.UploadData(url, data);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use the built-in .NET `JavaScriptSerializer` class you could use a third party one such as JSON.NET:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    States = new[] { new { State = "MX" } },
    Zip = "",
    Miles = "",
    PaginationStart = 1,
    PaginationLimit = 3
});
```

Comment: `Mexico_Schedule` is the variable's name. Not part of the json.

Comment: Darin, see my new question, please.

Comment: Which *new question* are you referring to more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the wrong content type.  You are posting x-www-form-urlencoded data, but setting content-type to "application/json"  Make your data match your content type, or vice-versa.

Comment: In the Ajax it works that way. If I set it to application/json, it does the same thing.